# How can i display values from 2 entites in one form using thymeleaf

Tags: java, hibernate, spring-boot, thymeleaf

I am using Spring Boot, Thymeleaf, Hibernate, and JPA to develop this application. I have mapped a relationship between the two entities I need to retrieve data from and am wondering how to display data from the two tables on the page

Can someone tell me how can I display values from 2 entities in one form using Thymeleaf? I can't find any tutorial, thanks in advance

```java
@Getter
@Setter
@NoArgsConstructor

@Entity
@Table(name = "users")
public class User {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;

    private String name;

    @OneToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    private UserDetails userDetails;

    public User(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }
}
```

```java
@Data
@NoArgsConstructor

@Entity
@Table(name = "user_details")
public class UserDetails {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;

    private String email;

    public UserDetails(String email) {
        this.email = email;
    }
}
```

Comment: you should be able very easily find what you need in Hibernate documentation. I suggest to go there first.

Answer (score 0):

A. If the both table is not related to each other then following solution may be work for you.

1. Create the One Model class.

   ```
   public class UserAndUsersDetails {

       private String name;

       private String email;

       public String getName() {
           return name;
       }

       public void setName(String name) {
           this.name = name;
       }

       public String getEmail() {
           return email;
       }

       public void setEmail(String email) {
           this.email = email;
       }
   ```

   }

2.Then call the database and get the result of it

```
User user = userRepository.get(id);
UserDetails userDetails = userDetailsRepository.get(id);
```

3.Set the data in userAndUsersDetails class

```
UserAndUsersDetails userAndUsersDetails = new UserAndUsersDetails()
userAndUsersDetails.setName(user.getName());
userAndUsersDetails.setEmail(userDetails.getEmail());
```

4.Send the UserAndUsersDetails class object to thymleaf.

B. If both table related to each other then following is best solution for it.

1.Extend the userDetails from user and clone it and donot put id in UserDetails Class

```
@Data
@NoArgsConstructor

@Entity
@Table(name = "user_details")

public class UserDetails extends User implements Cloneable {
private String email;

    public UserDetails(String email) {
        this.email = email;
    }

public UserDetails clone() {
UserDetails userDetails = new UserDetails();
userDetails.setName(this.getName());
}

}
```

2. Get the userDetils reslut

3.Send the object of it to thymelef.